# Calling a function from an object string compared to an object function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Why if I use

```js
const TokenProperties = {
  access_token: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("access_token")
}
```

instead of

```js
const TokenProperties = {
  access_token: ()=> PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("access_token")
}
```

and

```js
function getAccessToken() {

  // Makes REST API POST request for access token...
  // .......

  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
    .setProperty("access_token", access_token);
  return access_token;
}


function restCall (){
  
  checkToken(); // Let's say the access token is expired and this function calls getAccessToken() 

  // Why does...
  var restEndpoint = "https://api........."
  var head = {
    "Authorization":"Bearer "+ TokenProperties.access_token,   // <- This doesn't use the new token
    "Authorization":"Bearer "+ TokenProperties.access_token(), // <- This does (as I wanted)
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}
```

- Doesn't that line of code gets run after `checkToken()` is finished?
- What is the difference when calling the function from an object string 
  compared to calling it as an object function?
- How is the ordering of the functions getting called in the call stack?
- Should I be doing it like this? What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `TokenProperties` is a global variable, `access_token` value will be set before you call the `restCall()` and consequently the `checkToken()` method.
The method below would work.

```
function restCall (){
  
  checkToken();
  const TokenProperties = {
    access_token: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("access_token")
  }

  // ...
}
```

On the other hand, as @capchuck explained,

```
const TokenProperties = {
  access_token: ()=> PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("access_token")
}
```

defines only the `access_token` method body in the global variable and it is evaluated each time you call `TokenProperties.access_token()`

Best practice would be to use the method. What I usually do, I define a class MyProperties

```
class MyProperties{
  _get_property(key){
      return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(key)
  }

  getProperty1(){
    return this._get_property('property1')
  }

  getProperty2(){
    return this._get_property('property2')
  }
}
```

and use that class inside the method body like this
new Properties().getProperty1()

If you use Typescript, it is safe to do:

```
interface Keys{
  property1: any
  property2: any
  // ... 
}

class MyProperties{
  constructor(readonly properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()) {
    
  }

  get(key: keyof Keys): string | undefined {
    return this.properties.getProperty(key)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you store token as a string property, it computes once.
When you store it as a functions it computes each time called.

Ordering in JS is like a stack - Last In First Out.